# Checking if the space is empty or occupied in double ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

In my Tic-tac-toe program, there are three rows and three columns. The game will be played by two people.

The program will get user input via Scanner class(System.in) by typing in cell coordinate. I would like to prevent user from entering into an coordinate which has already been filled. I thought that it might be a good idea to implement this by using two(nested) 'for loops' which would check both rows and columns about whether they'd been already filled or not.

So in its first check, one slot will be occupied and if the user enters the same coordinate as the previous one, I can print a message to the user that the slot is not empty.

But the problem is that when these two nested for-loops run again(since I put them into a while loop where codes that switch between players is located), it will start to check again every cell in the Array table. And then the program will tell me that the slot has already been filled even though the second user does not enter the same coordinate as the second one.

I want the code to behave in a way that, it checks only a particular cell in the table right after a user has entered an coordinate for that cell.

My failed method, isOccupied(), looks like this --

```
public boolean isOccupied() {
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) { 
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            if (board.get(r).get(c) != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

And below is my while-loop;

```
while (scanner.hasNext() && !board.hasWon()){
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        int y = scanner.nextInt();          
        if (player){
            System.out.println("Player 2. Please enter your coordinate:");
            board.setPiece(x, y, "x");
            if (board.hasWon()){
                System.out.println(board);
                System.out.println("Player 1 has won!");
                break;

            }           
            else{
                player = false;
            }   
        }else {
            board.setPiece(x, y, "o");
            if (board.hasWon()){
                System.out.println(board);
                System.out.println("Player 2 has won!");
                break;
            }else{
                player = true;
            }

            System.out.println("Player 1. Please enter your coordinate:");
        }
        System.out.println(board);
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to implement this logic?

Comment: What is `board`? Can you show this class?

Comment: You should be implementing your board using a 2 dimensional array, not 2 lists. That way you can easily verify if a certain element is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isOccupied(int x, int y){

    return (board.get(x).get(y) != null);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```